# How do I run powershell scripts without admin rights?

Tags: powershell

If I try to change the execution policy, I get a message that says I can't modify the registry because I'm not an administrator.

It seems like this should be possible, since I can run batch files and other .exe and .com programs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try and set the policy of the process itself.

> powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy bypass

Comment: Of the 3 techniques I've seen, this is the simplest. Works at home, works at the office.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 23):

If your domain administrator hasn't forbidden it, you can do this:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```

This changes the default execution policy for PowerShell sessions run under the current user, rather than setting it for all users on the machine.

If you instead want to change the execution policy for just the current PowerShell session, you can use this command:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process
```

However, if your domain administrator is using the "[Turn on Script Execution](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113203942/http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/datacenter/set-the-powershell-execution-policy-via-group-policy/3305)" group policy, you will not be able to change your execution policy at all. The group policy setting makes the [Set-ExecutionPolicy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx) cmdlet ineffective.

Comment: I wouldn't know what group policy the admin's set at the office. I wonder if the policy stops the Invoke-Expression technique and the -EncodedCommand technique, which both allow the content of a script file to execute without modifying execution policy.

Comment: I would think not, but I haven't tested it. If PowerShell is enabled, you can always "run" a script by simply typing it into the command line. The goal of execution policy isn't really to stop a determined user, it's to prevent an unaware user from accidentally running untrusted scripts.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to have an easy way to run a script `myscript.ps1` from the windows shell then all you need is a bat `Runmyscript.bat` with the following contents:

```
type myscript.ps1 | powershell -
```

So simple it makes me wonder why you can't just run the ps1 in the first place, but there we go.

A generic version that prompts for userinput to type the name of the script would be:

```
set /p filename="Type name of script here: "
type %filename% | powershell -
```

I suppose if you wanted to, you could also write a generic vbscript script that opens any file in powershell using a dialogue box using this http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/windows-7-replacement-for.html

Answer (score 2):

how about

```
$script = Get-Content .\test.ps1
Invoke-Expression $script
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Try this: `cmd /min /C "set __COMPAT_LAYER=RUNASINVOKER && start "" %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"`

Answer (score 0):

The third technique I've found elsewhere on the internet is to use

powershell.exe -EncodedCommand  XXXXXXX

where XXXXXXX is the result of

```
$code = {
     #powershell script goes here.
    }
}

[convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($code))
```

Ref:
http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/powershell-script-in-a-bat-file/